# Reload AIR application remove Skin and background image in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.6

I am working on AIR application. In which i Put refresh button to refresh the application. When User click on Refresh Button following code refresh my application.

```
protected function onRefreshClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var app:WindowedApplication =
WindowedApplication(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);

var mgr:ProductManager =
new ProductManager("airappinstaller");

mgr.launch("-launch " +
                        app.nativeApplication.applicationID + " " +
                        app.nativeApplication.publisherID);

app.close();
}
```

Above code works nicely. 
Now, Again When application start then skinclass of button and backgroundImage of borderConatiner is not working.

```
<s:Button click="onRefreshClickHandler(event)" 
                  buttonMode="true" skinClass="skins.ButtonRefresh"/>
```

And:

```
<s:BorderContainer width="100%" borderVisible="false" 
                       backgroundImage="@Embed('assets/images/back.png')">
```

I don't know why this weird things happen.

Is there any solution for that?

 How can i get my skin back when i restart my application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I got the solution for my question. 

 I solve it by giving `skinclass` and `backgroundImage` at runtime on `creationComplete` like:

```
borderContainer.setStyle("backgroundImage","assets/images/back.png");
btnRefresh.setStyle("skinClass",CustomButtonRefreshSkin);
```

Hope, it will help someone else.